# OpenGL ES: How to apply a chain of filters to a texture with Render To Buffer ? and with shaders?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, render-to-texture

I'm a complete beginner of OpenGL, my current platform it iOS, I'm using the apple example GLImageProcessing which implements 5 different texture filters (contrats, brightness, etc).
This example applies one effect at the time to a fixed texture.

What I want to archive is to apply all the filters at once to the texture.

As fas as I understood there are 2 main ways of doing it:

- render to framebuffer
- use shaders

I already have some working code from the example for the filters, so I would like to avoid shaders for the moment.
If I understood correctly I'm in need to:

1. define an off screen buffer result that will produce a texture as result of the filtering process.
2. The next filter will be fed with the previously created. (Repeat N times)
3. Place the final texture on the main buffer

Unfortunately something is going wrong, "resultTexture" is always empty :(

Feel free to use shader if you think is more appropriate... help :)

```c
// A simple vertex format
typedef struct {
    GLfloat x, y, s, t;
} V2fT2f;

// Geometry flipping texcoords upside down
V2fT2f flipquad[4] = {
    { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    { 1, 0, 1, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 0 },
};

void drawGL(int wide, int high, float brightness, float contr )
{
    GLuint resultTexture;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrthof(0, wide, 0, high, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glScalef(wide, high, 1);

    // Remember the FBO being used for the display framebuffer
    glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES, (GLint *)&SystemFBO);

//Create offscreen buffer and an empty texture
    glGenTextures(1, &resultTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, resultTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, wide, high, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &ResultFBO);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, ResultFBO);
    glFramebufferTexture2DOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES,
                              GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES,
                              GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                              ResultTexture,
                              0);



//Brightness filter
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, ResultFBO);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sourceTexture);     //Bind the original texture
    glVertexPointer  (2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &flipquad[0].x);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &flipquad[0].s);

    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
    float t = brightness;
    if (t > 1.0f)
    {
        glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB,      GL_ADD);
        glColor4f(t-1, t-1, t-1, t-1);
    }
    else
    {
        glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB,      GL_SUBTRACT);
        glColor4f(1-t, 1-t, 1-t, 1-t);
    }
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_RGB,         GL_TEXTURE);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC1_RGB,         GL_PRIMARY_COLOR);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA,    GL_REPLACE);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_ALPHA,       GL_TEXTURE);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, SystemFBO);


//Repeat for every other filter
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, ResultFBO);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, resultTexture); //Bind the result texture
    glVertexPointer  (2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &flipquad[0].x);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &flipquad[0].s);
    // ... filter code
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, SystemFBO);


//Dispaly result step
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, SystemFBO);
    glViewport(0, 0, wide, high);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, resultTexture); //Bind the last result texture
    glVertexPointer  (2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &flipquad[0].x);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &flipquad[0].s);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

Comment: This will not work in OpenGL ES 2.0, you are creating a feedback loop by rendering into the same texture you are reading from (more importantly, invoking undefined behavior). In desktop OpenGL under ***very*** controlled circumstances this can be done, but this is not a legitimate use-case for doing that. What you want to do is ping-pong between at least two different textures when you chain your filters. For each filter, swap the textures you use for input and output.

Comment: Based on the example code he names in the question he's using 1.1. Not sure if that'll make a difference though -- and on some devices I believe ES 1.1 is emulated by 2.0.

Comment: @BenPious: You could be right, but half of his question talks about shaders.. which, to me automatically implies ES 2.0.

Comment: @Andon: Many of the functions in the code he posted aren't part of ES 2.0 (2.0 has no glTexCoordPointer, no glMatrixMode, you must use VBOs rather than glVertexPointer, etc.). He never calls glUseProgram between draw calls. And as he says at the top, there are two ways of doing it, one without shaders, and he wants to "avoid shaders." I agree it's kind of confusing though... Cesar: You never attach a depth buffer... is your FBO complete?

Comment: Thanks you both for the answers, unfortunately I'm a complete beginner in OpenGL :)  
Even if I don't fully understand the difference I understood that make sense for me to learn on OpenGL ES 2.0 whatever it means (ex. yes/no shaders). 
I guess have an idea about what I'm trying to do, so if you feel like posting a solution I'm open to various implementations. Theory is also very welcome :)

Comment: If you don't want to have to implement this all yourself, may I suggest this: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage ? I handle all the OpenGL ES filter rendering and FBO chaining you need for multiple filter passes in that project. Beyond that, Andon's right in that you'll need to do ping-pong rendering between FBOs for OpenGL ES (1.1 or 2.0), unless you want to use Apple's framebuffer read extensions, but that's a more complex topic.